# Uso de coma o punto después de la palabra "descuida"

Tags: gramática, puntuación, interjecciones

La palabra "descuida", a pesar de ser una conjugación del verbo "descuidar", me da la impresión de que también puede ser usada como interjección (en los diccionarios en línea lo mencionan como interjección).

Eso hace que me pregunte si debe usarse una coma o un punto para separar "descuida" del resto de una oración a la que introduce. Por ejemplo:

> Descuida, no es nada importante.

o

> Descuida. No es nada importante.

Y también me pregunto cómo puntuar cuando el "descuida" va seguido de un vocativo:

> Descuida, hijo, no es nada importante.

o

> Descuida, hijo. No es nada importante.

Answer (score 3):

Parece que es una [interjección impropia](https://dle.rae.es/?id=LuxJvnO):

> 1. f. Gram. interjección que se crea a partir de formas nominales, adjetivales, verbales o adverbiales; p. ej., ¡socorro!, ¡bravo!, ¡vaya!, ¡adelante!

Más concretamente, el DLE, en el artículo [descuidar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=CmcDdMR) recoge un ejemplo de su uso, colocando una **coma** después del "Descuida":

> 4. intr. U. en imperativo para tranquilizar a alguien que tiene una preocupación o para librarle de una tarea. *Descuida, que yo lo haré.*